# Error al querer abrir una ventana de windows forms

Tags: .net, windows-forms

Bueno tengo un problema al querer abrir los formularios de mi proyecto, anteriormente si funcionaba todo correctamente, pero como trabaja en una computadora que no era mía me lleve el proyecto a mi casa, después decidí regresar a la computadora de mi oficina, pero cuando intente abrir los archivos.cs que son los formularios de Windows, me marcaba el siguiente error:

> No se pudo resolver mscorlib para la versión de .NET Framework de
>   destino '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client'. Esto puede
>   ocurrir si no está instalada la versión de .NET Framework de destino o
>   si el moniker de .NET Framework tiene un formato incorrecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te recomiendo estos pasos de esta pagina [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/89b4b37e-ab4a-40ee-9562-3d1b8fe65bf7/error-al-cargar-aplicacion-mscorlib?forum=vsgenerales) fijate que en la respuesta te dice
Para corregirlo Fui a Proyecto -> Propiedades de Proyecto -> Depurar.
Alli me figuraba en el Dropdown "Plataforma" Any CPU y no me dejaba seleccionar (x86 activa) porque no estaba en el listado.

Dentro del Dropdown "configuracion" estaba en "Debug" y lo puse en "Release" ahi me apareció x86 a la derecha, apliqué los cambios y luego volví a poner Debug dentro del dropdown "configuracion"

Se solucionó el problema con la apertura de los forms.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por el punto, Si te sirvio la respuesta por favor marcala como valida. Saludos